# What is the difference between types and classes in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

What is the difference between the concept of “type” and “class” in Kotlin?  Is it the same as in Java?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean with "type", but the idea is the same as in Java: you have built-in basic types (boolean, int, float, etc), built-in classes (e.g. String, to name one), and then you can create your own types defining classes. Minor note: technically "basic" types are objects in Kotlin, however in Kotlin/JVM they're represented using the corresponding primitive types from the JVM

Comment: What do you mean, there's no primitive type in Kotlin.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar please see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html

Comment: @user2340612 You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: in Kotlin everything is an object, meaning you can invoke methods on everything (even though the internal representation might be relying on primitive types, as it happens with `Int` in Kotlin/JVM for example). This means that you can do `1.plus(2)` for example, which is not possible in plain Java. Then the compiler might and will change it depending on what's available in the targeted platform (e.g. the Kotlin/JVM compiler uses the primitive type `int` from the JVM instead of using the `Integer` class)

Answer (score 3):

It's similar to Java, yes.

A type is a more general concept than a class. Classes are a specific type of type, but there are other types. For instance, interfaces or type aliases. There are also generic types like `List<String>`, which are not classes. There is a generic `List` class which has one type parameter `T`, so it's written as `List<T>`, but the actual type `List<String>` doesn't have a corresponding class.

Types are conceptually sets of values. Saying that some value "is of some type" simply means that the value is part of the set represented by that type. Here are a few examples:

- the `Boolean` type is the set of the 2 values `true` and `false`
- the `Unit` type is the set containing a single value, which is the `Unit` object
- the `Nothing` type is the empty set and contains no values at all
- the `List<String>` type is the set of all possible lists of string values
- the `() -> Int` type is a function type, meaning that values of this type are functions. This particular type is the set of all functions that take no parameters and return a value of type `Int`

Now, Kotlin classes are concrete declarations of some types. A class is a type that can hold properties and methods, and be instantiated (we can create instances —values— of that class).

Comment: Don’t forget function types!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the idea is similar to Java. To oversimplify: classes are what you define, types are what you use.

A **class** is defined in a `class` block (or in an `object` block, or anonymously in an `object` expression). And of course there are many classes in the standard library, and other libraries.

A **type** is a characteristic of a reference, restricting the objects it can point to. The compiler checks the code for type-safety, to ensure that the types always make sense; it can also infer some types that aren't specified explicitly.

Types are derived from classes (and/or interfaces). In many cases, a class or interface defines a type directly. However:

- If a class or interface has type parameters (i.e. it's [generic](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html)), then it does not define a type itself (because Kotlin doesn't have raw types, unlike Java) but instead defines a family of types for different values of those type parameters. (This applies most obviously to the collection types, but also to function types, delegates, and many others.)
- There is also a [non-nullable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types) type corresponding to each nullable one (again, unlike Java).

Some examples may help to clarify:

Classes that are also types: `IntArray`, `String`, `Unit`.

Classes that are not types: `Array`, `ArrayList` (both generic).

Types that are not classes: `Int?` (non-nullable), `Array<Int>`, `(Int) -> Unit` (both generic), `CharSequence` (interface). (In each case, you can see how the type is derived from one or more classes/interfaces.)

Another difference is that while classes and interfaces exist at compile time and at run time, types apply fully only at compile time. (This is a result of [type erasure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#type-erasure), which means that type parameters are removed from the generated bytecode. However, unlike Java, Kotlin does preserve some type information in some cases: [`reified`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) type parameters are preserved, and also the compiler makes some nullability checks when interfacing with non-Kotlin code.)

Comment: This is much better explained than my answer, thanks for adding this!

Comment: @Joffrey Oddly enough, I thought your answer covered the core issue better than mine :-) I mainly added this coz I felt it was worth mentioning non-nullable types, function types (as Tenfour04 said!), a few more differences with Java, etc.